# joomla based owl Carousel

Tags: joomla, owl-carousel-2

We have a Joomla based school website, we have a owl carousel at the bottom that scrolls along.

I would like to make the images contained links to their to websites.

I've looked everywhere to find where the code for the owl carousel is but i cant find it. There is a module for it but it hasn't anywhere to alter the code.

The site URL is: http://www.kibworthprimary.org.uk

This is the code in the tmpl folder inside default.php

```
<div class="owlcarousel<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx ?> <?php echo $alias ?>" <?php if ($params->get('backgroundimage')) : ?> style="background-image:url(<?php echo $params->get('backgroundimage');?>)"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php echo $module->content;?>
    <div id="owl-carousel-<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?php foreach($gallery as $count=>$photo):
            $title = JString::ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", strstr($photo->filename, '.', 1))); ?>
            <div class="item">
                    <img class="lazyOwl img-responsive" src="<?php echo $photo->thumbImageFilePath; ?>" data-src="<?php echo $photo->thumbImageFilePath; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" title="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the code for the  module layout look like? You may want to post on [joomla.se].

Comment: thats just it, i can't find out where it's hosted. Within the module there is no code displayed

Comment: Say the module is called mod_owl. Go to your file system and find `/modules/mod_owl/tmpl` and paste the middle part (not all the copyright info etc) of the file in there  into your question.  Of if you have the zip file for the module on your computer unzip it and find that ile.

Comment: I've just looked in /modules/ but there isn't a folder for this module. I just don't get it. The module is called School Awards Slideshow and is based on the Owl Carousel but there are no folders listed that are anything to do with eithers awards or the owl carousel.

Comment: i was being stupid, we have multiple installations of joomla on various hosting accounts and i was ftp'ing into the incorrect one!

Answer (score 0):

In the end i looked at the HTML the module was producing and used that as a base. It was set to look at a directory of images and display them there but these images will not be changing and so that function wasn't needed.

All is now working by simple wrapping a href tag around the item lists.